# Mars mission trouble?

Tags: cipher

It's the year 2034 and you're a mission coordinator for the latest Mars mission. It has been a long haul but since the send off on January 12th the antimatter rocket has been a complete success. Your team just received the first transmission post landing sequence but you think something seems a little off about it. Can you figure out if and what the problem is?

The transmission follows

```
Hello Mission Control - 13.05.2034
WĔ have hađ absoluȶĔly no trouble at all, ĵust senдing our first notification ŧransmission. 
Planetary Orbit was successfully achieved and hopefully the UN will approve the next 
shipment soon. 
The last 2 weeks have been a real ordeal but the next 4 will be vitally important. 
ᥑl
```

Hint 1

> It will help to arrange all of the things that are wrong in the message. 
> Ex. 
> Non-ascii characters
> A notice about orbit being successful when you know the rocket has already gone through landing.
> An antimatter rocket shouldn't take four months to travel to Mars

Hint 2

> What passage in the message might make certain parts of unicode numbers important?

Comment: Well, first of all a bunch of the characters aren't ASCII: ĔđȶĔĵдŧᥑ - Joe Z.

Comment: Are the Unicode numbers important in this case, as the comment altered them?

Comment: Also note that the date is the 13th month, 5th day, 2034 or 13th day, 5th month, 2034

Comment: The message is dated 4 months after the launch - I would think that you'd want some form of communication to happen before then!

Comment: You might want to consider giving a hint or something.  Aside from spotting the unicode, there's really no direction to investigate this in.  Maybe tell us what the problem is, and ask how that was discovered from the message?

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering when a hint would be appropriate. Also the solution is pretty far out so I think I'd spend a bit more time making sure the solution is reachable easily in the next puzzle i submit.

Comment: Wait, exactly how long *would* it take to get to Mars with an antimatter rocket? I haven't seen the spec sheet on it.

Comment: By an article I read on the nasa.gov website nasa.gov/exploration/home/antimatter_spaceship.html it's estimated between one and a half to just under three months**

Comment: I ran across an article today about a couple of researchers who made simulation progress on the output of an antimatter rocket using today's technology and concluded 70% efficiently was possible. From this and a choosen acceleration of 1g the travel time could be considerably shorter.

Comment: Question closed [by request](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23091715#23091715).

Answer (score 4):

China, US and Europe are getting along fine, but US/Europe are not getting along with Russia.

Ĕ unicode u+0114 Latin (US Europe)

đ unicode u+0111 Latin (US Europe)

ȶ unicode u+0236 Latin (US Europe)

ĵ unicode u+0135 Latin (US Europe)

д unicode u+0434 Cyrillic (Russia)

ŧ unicode u+0167 Latin (US Europe)

ᥑ unicode u+1951 Tai Le (China)

We see in the transmission that 'ᥑl' the author (China) has had no trouble with the others 'WĔ have hađ absoluȶĔly' (US/Europe), but 'ĵust/ŧransmission' (US/Europe) is not getting along with 'senдing' (Russia).

Comment: While you're on the right track with looking at the characters, this isn't the solution I'm looking for. An interesting one though!